# Bicep: How do I make one module wait until a second module is ready?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I have a bicep with two modules.
The first module creates an Azure SQL server using:

```
Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview
```

The second module creates a database on this Azure SQL Server using:

```
Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-08-01-preview
```

The database creation (second module) fails because the Server (the first module) doesn't exist.

When I run it again, the database is created.

I assume there is some time before the server is ready, and the database creation runs too soon.

I get this error:

> The Resource
> 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-test-d-e2-001/databases/master' under
> resource group 'rg-testgroup-persist-d-001' was not found

How can I wait until the server is ready? Or is there a better fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bicep: How do I make one module wait until a second module is ready:-

The `dependsOn` property can be used to indicate that the second module is dependent on the first. This ensures that the first module gets created before the second module.

```bash
param  serverName  string = uniqueString('sql',  resourceGroup().id)
param  sqlDBName  string = 'SampleDB'
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
param  administratorLogin  string = 'newuser'
@secure()
param  administratorLoginPassword  string = 'xxxxxx'
resource  sqlServer  'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
name: serverName
location: location
properties: {
   administratorLogin: administratorLogin
   administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
  }
}
resource  sqlDB  'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {
parent: sqlServer
name: sqlDBName
location: location
sku: {
   name: 'Basic'
   tier: 'Basic'
}
dependsOn: [
    sqlServer
  ]
}
```

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql-db&tabs=CLI) for the sample template.

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group "Jahnavi" --template-file sql.bicep
```

[image]

[image]